# I have a Problem sending List data to MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model as follows

```
    public class CompanyDto
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CompanySocialNetworkTypeDto> CompanySocialNetworkTypeList { get; set; }

    }
    public class CompanySocialNetworkTypeDto
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }
        public string NetworkAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

for **CompanySocialNetworkTypeList** in Razor page :

```
    for (int j = 0; j < Model.CompanySocialNetworkTypeList.Count(); j++)
    {
        i = @j + 1;
        <tr id="tr-profile-@j" convertData="CompanySocialNetworkTypeList[@j]">
            <td scope="row">@i</td>
            <td>
                <div class="dropdown-select" id="select-profile-@j">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CompanySocialNetworkTypeList[j].Id,
                     new SelectList(socialNetworkTypeDtos, "Id", "Title", Model.CompanySocialNetworkTypeList[j].Id), new { @class = "form-control selectpicker",  style = "display:none" })
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.CompanySocialNetworkTypeList[j].NetworkAddress,
                    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",  type = "text" } })
            </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-profile" title="delete" id="delete-profile-@j"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    }
```

When I add a few records to CompanySocialNetworkTypeList and delete the first record
I can no longer send data to the controller
[image]

Fixed index problem in .serializeArray () but could not fix this problem in new FormData ()
please guide me
Thankful

Comment: Need the code to the behind page also.

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> Profile(CompanyModelDto companyModelDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

Comment: I'm using the  [BindProperty] on the page model to pass data back to the OnPost(). That is fairly reliable. What you have there has to go through the routing mechanism which is very sensitive and can be difficult to debug.

Comment: I can not use BindProperty here

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dto:

```
public class CompanySocialNetworkTypeDto
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }
        public string NetworkAddress { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
    }
```

And add hidden field IsDeleted inside of each row .

When you press your delete button don't try to remove this row inside of your javascript code just change IsDeleted value to True and  hide the whole row:

```
$("#div_row").addClass("d-none"); // just hide it
```

and inside of your on submit action

```
    CompanyDto.CompanySocialNetworkTypeList.RemoveAll(x => x.IsDeleted== true);
```